# symfony & apache friendly url

Tags: apache, symfony1, friendly-url

I am writing because after searching&reading i still have doubts about if i can make an url like this:
(a) http://www.balancextreme.es/tiendaweb/tienda/nuestrosProductos?culture=es

to show like this in search engines:
(b) http://www.balancextreme.es/pulseras-y-zapatillas-famosos.html

Doubts involved (and i hope this are usefull for others too!) are:

If i do it in htaccess (rewrite) will (i.e. google) show this one (even when url_for in the template is the (a) link)?
Or, if that`s not the case, can i achieve this in the routing.yml? (the examples i studied doesnt show this kind of change and i couldnt figure out how to do it)

well, that s it!
Someone can help on this?

thank

Answer (score 2):

If you're using Symfony, you should use the Symfony routing system...

There you could create a route like this:

```
#/apps/frontend/routing.yml:
show_product:
  url: /product/:slug
  params: { module: products, action: show }
```

Then, in your view, use `<?php echo link_to($product->name, 'show_product', array('slug' => $product->slug); ?>`.

If you solve your problem with mod_rewrite, which is possible, you miss the flexibility of referring to routes in your frontend. And if you change an URL, you'll have to manually change all references to that URL.

But this is the really compact explanation... You should really look into this tutorial, which explains everything very good: http://www.symfony-project.org/jobeet/1_4/Doctrine/en/05

Comment: let`s say i rewrite the url in htaccess.. will google publish this one or the original link?

Comment: Google indexes every URL it finds. If you rewrite it using .htaccess, you will need to refer to this new URL everywhere. If you don't do this, both url's will be added to the Google index. And that is considered "duplicate content", which is a negative factor for your page rank.